# url routing with parameter in angular js

Tags: angularjs, url, routes

I have this routing configuration in `app.js`:

```js
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: 
    {
        'contentView': 
        {
            templateUrl:'modules/login/login.html',
            controller:'loginCtrl'
        }
    },
    data:
    {
        login: true
    }
});
```

Whenever user hits the browser with URL `http://.../MyClient/#/?param=ParamValue`.

It will take the user to the login page and I am able to access the param value as well.

There is a logout button in the successive pages and after logout, I want to redirect to the initial URL and if I try something like

```js
$location.path('/#/?param=ParamValue');
```

the user will stay on the same page and URL will be like this:

```
http://.../MyClient/#/%23/%3Fparam=ParamValue
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use the $state service to navigate between your states, `$state.go('home', {param: ParamValue})`

also add the parameter you need in the url template for the state.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/?param',
    views: 
    { ....
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1

Comment: Its redirecting to home state but parameters are not coming in URL means now url is http://..../MyClient/#

Comment: I dont understand the question, you can order your question and try to explain more that i could help you please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I have reconfigured the routing in such a way that routing will work with state parameter.

Comment: @user3522467 I edited the answer adding the url template part that was missing